# Tricky elementary proof with limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ be a function from $(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable and satisfies the following:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) &= \infty\\
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) &= -2.
\end{align}

Prove that there is a point $x_0$ of the domain so that $f'(x_0)=-1$.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: My idea was to use Lagrange but... no idea how

Comment: I believe that you need $f$ to be continuously differentiable. Otherwise, you would be able to construct a function so that the derivative jumps past -1.

Comment: @CZiegler What about Darboux theorem ? Doesn't it state that a derivative satisfies the intermediate value ? So I don't think you need it to be continuously differentiable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)

Answer (score 4):

Consider $g(x)=x+f(x)$. The statement is the same as saying there is $x_0$ with $g'(x_0)=0$.

Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)=\infty=\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)
$$
the function has an absolute minimum. What's the derivative there?

Comment: Concise and clear!  (+1)

Comment: @Dr.MV I had a silly downvote to clean up. ;-)

Comment: +1 for shortest possible answer and also to deal with nefarious... :)

Answer (score 1):

There exist points $a,b$ with $b>a$ such that

Somewhere in $(0,a), f'(x) < -M$ where $M$ is large (certainly $M>1$)

Somewhere in $(b,\infty), f'(x) > -\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is small (greater than $0$ less than $1$)

And if $f'(x)$ is continuous, then there is an $c\in(a,b)$ where $f'(c) = -1$ by the intermediate value theorem.

There is still some work for you still do to prove each of propositions above, but it gives you the framework.

Comment: I think you need to switch your inequalities and make $M$, $\epsilon$, and $f'(c)$ negative, since the function is going from large to small.

Comment: @CZiegler Multiply through by $-1$ :)

Comment: What if the derivative is itself not a continuous function?

Comment: @john A differentiable function can never have a jump discontinuity, or the function ceases to be differentiable at that point.  It can have and essential discontinuity, but in that case you should still be able to show that somewhere the $f'(x)$ passes through $-1$